# HTTP Listener takes around 60 seconds to Start

Tags: .net, port, firewall, antivirus, httplistener

I need to use the HTTP Listener(TCP Sockets are not allowed here). So, i create the HTTPListener as below. Start the process with Administrator Privileges.

```
    Dim httpServer = New HttpListener()
    httpServer.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8181/")
    httpServer.Start()
```

When the above code runs, it takes around 40-60 seconds in the httpServer.Start() method **in only ONE system**.

I have analysed around another 20 machines. They are able to start the httpServer in milliseconds, but that particular machine is taking a minimum of 40 seconds each time.

Keeping in mind that, an antivirus may scan/delay the opening of Port, I tried disabling the Firewall and Antivirus on that system, but it made no difference.

Any ideas what might be different in this machine than the other ones?

Comment: Could it be trying to resolve auto-configure proxy settings? Does it do this if you try to browse the web as well or just when setting up a listening socket?

Comment: @lc. WebBrowsing is working fine...